# Add a form of notification for answers after a year

Tags: discussion, notifications

I'm not quite sure about details of this right now, hence this is tagged discussion.

---

Currently, people will often post an answer and then leave it and forget about it. While others can edit and update a post, sometimes only the OP can evaluate it accurately, update broken links and maybe even delete it if it's no longer needed.

I'm suggesting a form of notification (not too intrusive, and easy to ignore) that will remind people to check on their answers to ensure they are still up to date, relevant and useful one year after they last edited / viewed it.

I don't know how this would work - especially as I'm sure active users don't want 10 notifications a day for their posts.

This could help keep outdated / wrong answers away and if applied to questions as well could avoid outdated accepted answers.

Could this work?

Comment: Except broken links, all answers should be assumed as relevant & useful, provided enough information. The "up to date" part is a bit troublesome, since user can comment to notify OP, or just write answer with up to date info. Back to broken links, that's why the best way is to quote the content itself. That's also the reason why we should always try to write a self-contained answer in the first place, and this feature shouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 8):

I think scheduling notifications to users as reminders that they should check in on their old Q&As would be intrusive.

I think we should stay with our current model of "fix 'em as we find 'em".

That way only users involved in the Q&As with an actual problem need to be alerted (via a comment ping, or edit notification, or maybe a downvote) that their question or answer may need attention.